# tweepy Not Authorized - tweepy.error.TweepError: Not authorized

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I get the following error when I try to use tweepy for twitter authentication.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/models.py", line 146, in followers
    return self._api.followers(user_id=self.id, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 173, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Not authorized.
```

I am not building a web app. So, authentication is simpler.

```
consumer_key="----------"
consumer_secret="----------"
access_token="--------------"
access_token_secret="-----------------"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.get_user('---').followers()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fixed. The particular user had protected tweets. Hence, .followers() was failing.

Comment: Fixed? In the new version? I'm still using 2.3.0

Comment: ```    except tweepy.TweepError as ex:
        if ex.reason == "Not authorized.":
            # do something here
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a **for** that looped through my followers in order to get all their followers. And i got crashed with the same error.
My workaround was:

```
try:
    api.get_user('---').followers()
    ...
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print("Failed to run the command on that user, Skipping...")
```

Although it makes you miss some of the users. My loop has successfully finished and got about 99% percent of my followers. So It is probably really rare that a user has protected tweets.